# Android-Things GPS Service bound to main activity or separate activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, gps, android-things

I am developing code for simple robotic automation on Android-Things using GPS and a number of sensors (magnetometer, gyro, accelerometer, camera, etc.) and outputting signals to a number of motors.

Having that in mind, should I setup the GPS et al. as bound services to the main activity or bound to their own activity, or some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an activity if there is user involvement (button clicks etc).
Use a service if it should run in the background.

Depending on your case, if the user wants to turn the service on, you may have a button starting the background service and activity destroys itself.

Can you be clear about how the flow should look like?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still trying to determine the code flow, though I think it will have a standby state wherein the user enters parameters such as GPS waypoints if the current autonomous activity is waypoint finding, or others depending on the autonomous activity.  Once they are setup the system will be set to autonomous mode.

I think your latter suggestion would work well.  Use an activity to get GPS et al while in setup mode, then a service once it's in autonomous mode (eg - at the press of a button).

Does that sound like a correct understanding of what you said?

Comment: Is there a reason NOT to use a service the entire time? (and turn it off when unused)

Comment: Yes, you can always have the service, but still need to decide how you are gonna start it. Now, we have background restrictions introduced from OREO too

Comment: Learn something everyday, thanks @dcanh121   : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background